# Divide factor levels in the same column to obtain a new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like the following example (here, there is a dataframe containing two simulations for each round, condition and treatment):

```
df <- data.frame(Sim=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),Round=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),Condition=c('A1','A1','A2','A2','A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B1','B2','B2','B1','B1','B2','B2','A1','A1','A2','A2','A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B1','B2','B2','B1','B1','B2','B2'),Treatment=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),Output=c(3,2.5,2.1,1.9,2.8,2.3,2.0,1.6,2.6,2.7,1.3,1.2,2.4,2.3,1,1.1,2,1.3,1.3,0.9,2,2.1,2.1,1.2,2,1.7,1.2,1,2,1.3,0.5,0.4))
```

*Condition* encompasses four levels: A1, A2, B1, B2.

Now, I'd like to manipulate this dataframe in order to get the *Output* reduction (%) that A2 produces on A1 (1-(A2/A1) for each simulation, round, condition and treatment. The same for B2 on B1 (1-(B2/B1).

We should obtain a new dtaframe similar to this ("New output" here is not based on the dataframe):

```
Round    New condition  Treatment   Newoutput
1        1-(A2/A1)      1           0.3
1        1-(A2/A1)      1           0.24
...
1        1-(B2/B1)      2           0.5
1        1-(B2/B1)      2           0.56
...
2        1-(A2/A1)      1           0.43
2        1-(A2/A1)      1           0.23
...
2        1-(B2/B1)      1           0.4
2        1-(B2/B1)      1           0.5
...
```

I have been trying to `split` the original dataframe, but not sure how I could then operate over it. I also tried to operate directly over the dataframe by using `transform`. No success so far.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you have multiple `Output` values for each `Round`, `Condition` and `Treatment` which value to consider to calculate ?

Comment: In the example I am providing data for two simulations. I have added this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first `split` `Output` on `Condition`, then select `1` and `2` values alternately and apply the formula for each of them using `mapply`

```
lst <- with(df, split(Output, Condition))
mapply(function(x, y) 1-(y/x), lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)], lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])

#             A1        B1
#[1,]  0.3000000 0.5000000
#[2,]  0.2400000 0.5555556
#[3,]  0.2857143 0.5833333
#[4,]  0.3043478 0.5217391
#[5,]  0.3500000 0.4000000
#[6,]  0.3076923 0.4117647
#[7,] -0.0500000 0.7500000
#[8,]  0.4285714 0.6923077
```

Or maybe directly if you want them as one vector

```
unname(1 - (unlist(lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])/unlist(lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)])))
#[1]  0.3000000  0.2400000  0.2857143  0.3043478  0.3500000  0.3076923 -0.0500000  
#     0.4285714  0.5000000 0.5555556  0.5833333  0.5217391  0.4000000  0.4117647  
#     0.7500000  0.6923077
```

---

If the dataframe is not in correct order you can arrange them first and then use the above

```
df <- df[order(df$Condition), ]
```

Or if the levels are not fixed, it can rearranged manually

```
df <- df[order(match(df$Condition, c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"))), ]
```

Of if there are many more levels, you can do

```
df <- df[order(match(df$Condition, paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3],each = 2), rep(1:2, 3)))), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ronak. It works fine with the example I provided. The problem is that in my real dataframe I have six levels for "Condition" (A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2). Also, the order of this levels is not exactly the same as here, so I can not use the strategy of selecting values alternately...

Comment: @pyring You can `order` them first. See the updated answer.

Comment: however, if I order the dataframe this way I get something like this `Condition=c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","B1","B1","B1","B1","B2","B2","B2","B2","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C2")`. Thus, I guess I need to sort the list in another way. Maybe my minimal example was not very good and it is better a link to data over dropbox.

Comment: @pyring No, I think that is the way you want it right? Then when you select alternate  values you get `A1`, `B1` and `C1` together and the `2`s in another list.